# SQL Server DAC FX SchemaComparison SchemaCompareDatabaseEndpoint fails with no IntegratedSecuirty

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find newly created tables in the target database on publishing. Using DAC Fx I am able to find the differences and delete the tables after moving the newly created table to another db.

I developed and tested the code with IntegratedSecurity. Started failing on machines with SQLServer logins.

The moment I toggle the IntegratedSecurity to true it works. Is it a bug?

```
 private void Analyse()
{
            try
            {
                var sourceDacpac = new SchemaCompareDacpacEndpoint(DacPacSrc);                
                var csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConnectionString);
                csb.IntegratedSecurity = false;
                var targetDatabase =new SchemaCompareDatabaseEndpoint(csb.ToString());


                var comparison = new SchemaComparison(sourceDacpac, targetDatabase);
                comparison.Options.DropObjectsNotInSource = true;
                var result = comparison.Compare();
                if (result.GetErrors().Any())
                {
                    throw new Exception("Compare failed " + result.GetErrors().FirstOrDefault().Message);
                }

                var delta = new List<string>();
                if (result.Differences != null && result.Differences.Any())
                {
                    var deltaTables = result.Differences.Where(x => x.Name == "Table" && x.UpdateAction == SchemaUpdateAction.Delete);
                    delta = deltaTables.Select(x => x.TargetObject.Name.ToString()).ToList();
                }

                FindingDeltaCompleted?.Invoke(this, new DeltaEventArgs(delta));

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logging.HandleException(ex); 
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `Persist Security Info=True` in the SQL Authentication connection string.

SSDT/DAC Fx saves connection strings in registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SSDT\ConnectionStrings`. When `Persist Security Info=True` is not set, it won't restore the password when loading the connection strings from registry.